# How can I restrict the API calls in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am the admin and multiple people are working on the project. New routes are being created everyday(basically APIs). I want a central record of all the routes(controllers and respective actions). I want a route to work only if it is listed in that record(yml file).
I have heard that it is possible to manage the resources by creating a yml file, though being new to rails I am not sure how to do it.

Suggestions would be highly appreciated.

---

I think I need to be more explicit about the query I have. 
Agreed that we need to list all the GET,POST PUT AND DELETE requests in route in order to redirect a call.
What I am looking for is another YML file which will have the contollers and  respective actions listed. The actions listed here should only be allowed to be routed and not others present in the route.rb.

Example :
I have the following route:

GET "fetch_ids" => "get_id#select"

Now if "get_id#select" is listed in my YML only then a route would be allowed.

How can I set this up?

Comment: Sounds like anarchy! You shouldn't solve organisational problems with technology, it rarely works.

Answer (score 0):

It already works like that. No matter if you create a controller or an action, the controller and the action will be accessible only if they are somehow listed in the `routes.rb` file.

You can have 10 controllers, but just one in the `routes.rb`. The other 9 will not be reachable.

To list all the routes simply run

```
$ rake routes
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i think i need to be more explicit about the query. 
Agreed that we need to list all the GET,POST PUT AND DELETE requests in route.
What I am looking for is another YML file which will have the contollers and  respective actions listed. The actions listed here should only be allowed to be routed and not others present in the route.
Example :
I have the following route:

GET "fetch_ids" => "get_id#select"

Now if "get_id#select" is listed in my YML only then a route would be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To have a list of all routes that available, please try this Rack app (part of config/routes.rb)

```
match "/secret_routes" => proc { |env| [ 200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, [Application.routes.routes.collect{|i| i.path.spec.to_s}.join("\n")] ] }
```